# Problem installing GAZEBO on ubuntu 12.10 (broken package)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey guys, i was trying to install gazebo in my ubuntu 12.0, following the steps in "gazebosim.org/wiki/1.2/install" . However, after i input

```
sudo apt-get install gazebo
```

in terminal as step 4 suggested, it shows up the following errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gazebo : Depends: libboost-thread1.46.1 but it is not installable
          Depends: libboost-signals1.46.1 but it is not installable
          Depends: libboost-system1.46.1 but it is not installable
          Depends: libboost-filesystem1.46.1 but it is not installable
          Depends: libboost-program-options1.46.1 but it is not installable
          Depends: libboost-regex1.46.1 but it is not installable
          Depends: libboost-iostreams1.46.1 but it is not installable
          Depends: libcegui-mk2-0.7.5 but it is not installable
          Depends: sdformat (>= 1.4.7~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

to fix it, but its still not working. Please, any suggestions or commnets will be appreciated XD

Eason.Lee

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5732/problem-installing-gazebo-on-ubuntu-12.10--(broken-package)/) by [libra](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/701/libra/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2014-03-27**:
Could you please update the answer with the output of these commands: "ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/" ,"apt-get install sdformat" and "apt-get install libboost-iostreams1.46-dev". Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm on Precise not Quantal but I see a similar error.

```
$ sudo apt-get install gazebo
:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gazebo : Depends: sdformat (>= 1.4.7~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`sudo apt-get install sdformat` let me run `sudo apt-get install gazebo` without an error. Credit goes to @Jose Luis Rivero.

---

Originally posted by [IsaacS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/15/isaacs/) with karma: 118 on 2014-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2014-11-19**:
Glad to help! :)